# create image from png, convert to base64

Tags: php, image, base64

I want to open a image url, convert it to an image, so I can use `imagecopymerge()` on it, then convert that to base64.

I was able to view the image data using `file_get_contents`, but I'm not sure how to combine that with `imagecreatefromstring`, `imagecopymerge`, and `base64_encode`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I finally did it was to use

```
$img=imagecreatefrompng('url');
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$imgString=ob_get_clean();
$imgBase64=base64_encode($imgString);
```

I found out that I can't convert an image to a string, and have to use the buffer.